# Short Sci Fi about a young boy who grows up to be a famous musician

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

The story's protagonist was a young boy with epilepsy who is taken by his mother to some place with water, but not the ocean.  There are shards of glass or pottery.  It turns out that they are being used by little beings to create a barrier.   They communicate in what sound like chimes, or bells.  He helps save them from what, in my memory, may have been snails.  He goes on to become a famous (real) musician, in whose work the sound of the chimes they made were reflected....im sorry, it's a short sci fi story.

Comment: Short story? Short film? Short animation? Where did you see it? When?

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and [edit] in any further details elicited by those questions.